# Reading local file with lxml -Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have what I thought was very basic code to read an xml file into Python. But I'm baffled that I'm running into issues.

I thought this code should work:

```
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser(ns_clean=True, recover=True)
tree = etree.parse('file.xml', parser)
#root = tree.getroot()
```

However, I get this issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Root/Documents/xml.py", line 5, in <module>
    tree = etree.parse('file.xml', parser)
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 3519, in lxml.etree.parse
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1839, in lxml.etree._parseDocument
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1865, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1769, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1163, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 601, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 711, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 638, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
OSError: Error reading file 'file.xml': failed to load external entity "file.xml"
```

I read a few posts with similar issues, and it turns out that the problem was not including the full path. So I've run the code with a few iterations:

```
tree = etree.parse(r'C:\Users\Root\Documents\file.xml', parser)
tree = etree.parse("C:\\Users\\Root\\Documents\\file.xml", parser)
tree = etree.parse('C:/Users/Root/Documents/file.xml', parser)
```

Am I missing something obvious? Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Works for me, although I can duplicate by renaming file.xml. Does a simple `open("file.xml")` work? You could `import os;print(os.getcwd())` to see which directory you are in.

Comment: @tdelaney thanks for the advice. The ```open``` command worked without error, and I was in the correct directory ```"C:\Users\Root\Documents"``` Not sure why the ```etree.parse``` command would throw an error

Comment: Do you have external entities in file.xml? My entire file was "<foo/>".

Comment: Hmm I don’t believe that I have external entities in the file, but it’s also too big for me to open in any other softwares to confirm. Is there perhaps a way I could confirm with Python?

Comment: I'd suggest lxml but... well... that already seems to be the problem. But there is lxml's iterparse https://lxml.de/3.2/parsing.html#iterparse-and-iterwalk which gives you events as it parses. It may give a better hint.